# In liferay, how do I redirect to the login page and back?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

In my doView mehtod, under certain conditions (based on the url parameters), I would like to require that the user login before continuing.

I am basically trying to reproduce the behaviour of guest trying to access a private page: the user is redirected to the login page, then back to the original page after login.

What code should I put in my doView method to reproduce this ?

Thanks and Best regards,
Alain

PS. I am using liferay 6.1 GA3

Comment: Havent tried this but can you redirect user to url like /c/portal/login?redirect=currenturl . currenturl will be url that you want to come back

Comment: Pankaj, this indeed works. Could you post this as an answer and I will flag it as such ? Thanks, Alain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect user to url like `/c/portal/login?redirect=currenturl`.

Here, currenturl will be URL where you want to come back.

Comment: its not working if my **currenturl** contains any special character  .. Is there any limitation of liferay.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Your have to encode the password. Password may have some special character so use URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8").